# Smartsheet cell link object does not return a status

Tags: python, smartsheet-api

```
ss_client = SmartCap.SMARTSHEET.get_client(self)

cell_link = ss_client.models.CellLink()
cell_link.sheet_id = int(source_sheet_id)
cell_link.sheet_name = source_sheet_name
cell_link.row_id = int(source_row_id)
cell_link.column_id = int(source_col_id)

print(cell_link.status)
```

Above is a simplified version of my code. I have checked all the source id codes with the get_cell_history() method and they are correct. However when I set the cell link object's attributes to the source cell's attributes, I get a cell_link.status = None. I did a little digging through the smartsheet module and found the CellLinkStatus should only return 8 possible messages (OK, BROKEN, INACCESSIBLE, NOT_SHARED, BLOCKED, CIRCULAR, INVALID, or DISABLED) i.e. not None. This makes no sense because all of the required attributes are set in order to get a status update back. Is there an update cell link method or something else that I am missing that would trigger the @setter method for cell_link.status?

Edit: adding the remainder of the code

```
new_cell = ss_client.models.Cell()
new_cell.value = None
new_cell.link_in_from_cell = cell_link
new_cell.column_id = dest_column_id

new_row = ss_client.models.Row()
new_row.id = dest_row_id
new_row.cells.append(new_cell)
result = ss_client.Sheets.update_rows(dest_sheet_id, new_row)
```

This results in in a "Required object attribute(s) are missing from your request: cell.value." error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

sorry I didn't see this earlier. CellLink is a special case because not only does `value` have to be `None`, but we actually have to serialize a null in the JSON construct that gets PUT to the API. In the Python SDK there is an ExplicitNull model, which causes the serializer to do just that (serialize the null/None). In most cases any attribute with no value would just get dropped during serialization.

Here is a sample from the test code:

```
    sheet_b = smart_setup['sheet_b']
    cell_link = smart.models.CellLink()
    cell_link.sheet_id = sheet_b.id
    cell_link.row_id = sheet_b.rows[0].id
    cell_link.column_id = sheet_b.columns[0].id

    cell = smart.models.Cell()
    cell.column_id = col_id
    cell.link_in_from_cell = cell_link
    cell.value = smart.models.ExplicitNull()

    row = smart.models.Row()
    row.id = added_row.id
    row.cells.append(cell)

    action = smart.Sheets.update_rows(sheet.id, [row])
    assert action.request_response.status_code == 200
```

Comment: Thank you sir! If you have a BTC or ETH address, I'd like to buy to you a beer.

Comment: Haha...made my day. Glad I could help.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't sent anything to the server. You need to update the Row. See https://github.com/smartsheet-samples/python-snippets/blob/04951c2ca8ae1a97386bdd3fa6e010f2845e1421/samples.py#L47

Comment: Hi Steve, the code continues on to update the server with the ss_client.Sheets.update_rows(dest_sheet_id, rows) as described in your sample code (thank you for the sample btw, it was very helpful). However, when I attempt the update_rows() method, I get an obj.value error. That is weird considering A.) the value is explicitly set to None and B.) a cell object that has its .link_in_from_cell attribute set to a cell link object can not also have a cell.value.      That is what led me to believe the cell_link object is not being properly set up.

Answer (score 0):

Michael, although I wasn't able to replicate your exact error, I did get your code to work with a minor change—making the `new_row` part of an array when it's passed to the `update_rows` function.

```
cell_link = ss_client.models.CellLink()
cell_link.sheet_id = int(source_sheet_id)
cell_link.row_id = int(source_row_id)
cell_link.column_id = int(source_col_id)

new_cell = ss_client.models.Cell()
new_cell.value = None
new_cell.link_in_from_cell = cell_link
new_cell.column_id = dest_column_id

new_row = ss_client.models.Row()
new_row.id = dest_row_id
new_row.cells.append(new_cell)

result = ss_client.Sheets.update_rows(dest_sheet_id, [new_row])
```

Although the [Update Row docs](https://smartsheet-platform.github.io/api-docs/?python#update-rows) indicate that the `update_row` function will accept a "Row object or an array of Row objects", I was **only** able to get it working with an array. I think that's a result of how the API is implemented in the Python SDK.

Let me know whether the above code fixes your issue. It is successfully creating cell links for me.

Comment: Hi Taylor, thanks for the response. I have tried your suggestion and received the same error. In fact, I copied the script linked above and ran it with my ID numbers . However, I get the same cell.value error!?!?! I've also validated the row/column/sheet IDs for both the destination and source sheets. The only thing that has caught my attention is the cell_link.status = None after the 3 req’d attributes have been assigned. I’m thinking this is why the cell obj is not being treated as a cell link and throwing the cell value error. I'm running smartsheet version 1.3.3. Suggestions?

Comment: P.S. I would give you an upvote but I'm apparently not reputable enough. ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: In the Smartsheet UI on the specific cell you're trying to add the link to, try typing a string, saving the sheet, deleting the string, and then saving the sheet. Then try the script one more time.

Comment: I also noticed that blank cells only return a column ID with the get_row() method. Fortunately, the person below explained why the null value was not being set. Thanks for taking the time to  provide suggestions.